# Python's debugger's step-through and free-running modes follow different execution paths

Tags: python, debugging

If I run the script

```
import sys
if sys.gettrace():
    print 'OK'
else:
    assert False, 'good grief'
```

...like this

```
% python -mpdb bugdemo.py
```

...(Python v. 2.7.8) I first see a prompt like this:

```
-> import sys
(Pdb)
```

If at this point, I repeatedly enter `s` to step through the script, I see something like this:

```
> <path-to-script>/bugdemo.py(2)<module>()
-> if sys.gettrace():
(Pdb) s
> <path-to-script>/bugdemo.py(3)<module>()
-> print "OK"
(Pdb) s
OK
--Return--
> <path-to-script>/bugdemo.py(3)<module>()->None
-> print "OK"
(Pdb)
```

But, if instead of stepping through the code, at the first debugger prompt I just enter `c` (short for `cont`, i.e. *continue*), ***the code's execution follows a different path***:

```
% python -mpdb bugdemo.py
> <path-to-script>/bugdemo.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yt/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/Users/yt/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/Users/yt/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 387, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bugdemo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sys
AssertionError: good grief
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> <path-to-script>/bugdemo.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Is this a bug<sup>1</sup> that I should report?  Or is there a way to rationalize it?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>If this is a bug, it is *a whopper of a bug*: a debugger that follows different execution paths in step-through and free-run is worse than useless.</sup>

Comment: so, you've got code that checks whether you are running under a debugger or not, and it runs differently under a debugger. this seems like intended behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

`lib\bdb.py:227`

```
def set_continue(self):
    # Don't stop except at breakpoints or when finished
    self._set_stopinfo(self.botframe, None, -1)
    if not self.breaks:
        # no breakpoints; run without debugger overhead
        sys.settrace(None)
        frame = sys._getframe().f_back
        while frame and frame is not self.botframe:
            del frame.f_trace
            frame = frame.f_back
```

I.e. `pdb` removes the trace function in some circumstances which is its private business. You try to outsmart it by checking its presence and thus shoot yourself in the foot. Congratulations on that.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for settrace and gettrace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) pretty clearly state the they are intended to be used to implement debuggers. Presumably pdb is using settrace, and when pdb isn't run beforehand, I would assume that gettrace returns None.

What were you expecting to happen? That pdb would set up an environment that would perfectly hide from you the fact that a debugger is there, even when you explicitly use functions that are intended as hooks for a debugger? I really don't think this is a bug. The docs linked above even say: (emphasis mine)

> CPython implementation detail: The settrace() function is **intended only for implementing debuggers, profilers, coverage tools and the like.** Its behavior is part of the implementation platform, rather than part of the language definition, and thus may not be available in all Python implementations.

gettrace and settrace are odd little corners of the language intended for "magic" uses, like debuggers. If you don't know what they do, just don't call them.

Comment: Irrelevant. The docs clearly say what `gettrace` does. They only warn that is might be missing in other implementations.

Comment: The OP seems absolutely gobsmacked that functions related to debugging give different results depending on what the debugger is doing. I don't think it's irrelevant to point out that the function the OP is calling is not intended for general use.